# Method you can only run in a constructor

Tags: c#, constructor

Is there a way to mark a method in c# so it can only run in the constructor?  Basically, I have a load of read only string arrays that I need to update with the base columns in the constructor so I do the following:

```
    public CMSBlogContext(ICMSRelationshipContext relationshipContext)
    {
        _relationshipContext = relationshipContext;
        ColumnNames.AddBaseColumns(ref _blogAuthorColumns);
        ColumnNames.AddBaseColumns(ref _blogCardColumns);
        ColumnNames.AddBaseColumns(ref _blogCategoryColumns);
        ColumnNames.AddBaseColumns(ref _blogPageColumns);
        ColumnNames.AddBaseColumns(ref _blogPostColumns);
    }
```

I thought I could tidy this up by moving the columns into a separate function like so:

```
    public CMSBlogContext(ICMSRelationshipContext relationshipContext)
    {
        _relationshipContext = relationshipContext;
        AddBaseColumns();
    }

    private void AddBaseColumns() 
    {
        ColumnNames.AddBaseColumns(ref _blogAuthorColumns);
        ColumnNames.AddBaseColumns(ref _blogCardColumns);
        ColumnNames.AddBaseColumns(ref _blogCategoryColumns);
        ColumnNames.AddBaseColumns(ref _blogPageColumns);
        ColumnNames.AddBaseColumns(ref _blogPostColumns);
    }
```

But obviously this complained that read only can only be updated in the constructor, so is there a way to make a method only able to run in the constructor (or rather, is there a way to put those read only updates into a method not in the constructor but will only run in the constructor)?

Comment: The problem on this is: what to do if `AddBaseColumns` itself calls a method, that is only called by `AddCBaseColumns` and thus *implictely* by the constructor? How would you mark that last method?

Comment: Don't have a function called `AddBaseColumns`, make one called `GetBaseColumns` that you can then assign to things in the constructor.

Comment: Its amazing question.  Looking into partial methods may help

Comment: Voting to reopen as I think there is a possible answer to this particular question.

Comment: Reading more into it _THIS IS SOMETHING TOTALLY DIFFERENT_ than the dupe, please vote to reopen.

Comment: @Mafii Of course there is an answer: within the duplicate.

Comment: @HimBromBeere the question differs a lot imo.

Comment: @Mafii It was closed by community user which means OP agrees it's a dupe.

Comment: @DavidG there is a solution that doesn't fit the dupe question. Private, parameterless constructors. I already have my answer written down, but can't answer. It's close to what primebydesign did.

Comment: Create a class which should contain all the code to be executed in constructor.  Move all the read only field to it.  Inherit from that class and call :base()   with constructor

Comment: totally agree @Ramankingdom. If your code within the constructopr is so complex that it needs its own method, why not extract a class instead and set the variables within its constructor?

Comment: @Mafii Again, OP himself closed this question, so he accepted the answer provided there already.

Comment: @HimBromBeere the other question is specifically asking for "If there is any pattern". We can, without any problem, reopen the question if we don't think it's a dupe. And I don't think it is.

Comment: I can´t see how this makes OPs code any different. See OPs first constructor. He explicitely wants to *not use* the class´ constructor obviously.

Comment: He doesn't wan't to use _this specific_ constructor probably. Using a base class or private constructor to call from the main one is different imo.

Comment: Sorry, I closed it as I thought there was no way to do it

Comment: I agree with @Mafii that there isn't a 1-to-1 mapping between this question and the suggested duplicate. I don't believe it's reasonable to expect everyone to infer an answer from another that's conceptually similar. Also, OP was compelled to close by community feedback but he has a valid question.

Comment: If a variable in your constructor needs enough code so that in a method would look more beautiful, but you don't want the property be {get; set; } then, convert the method in a Func<>. That way, you can have something like this:

public T InitVariable { get; }
public Constructor ()
{
    InitVariable = FuncInitializer();
}
Func<T> FuncInitializer => () => T;

Answer (score 2):

One thing you could do is to use a base class and put the properties on that. Then you could use the base class' constructor to set up the read only fields like so:

```
  public class Test:TestBase {

    public Test(): base() { 

    }

    public string GetExample() { 
     return example;
    }

}

    public class TestBase {
    protected readonly string example = "";

     public TestBase() { 
      example ="hi";
    }

}
```

I can now use this like so and it works:

```
var test = new Test();
Console.WriteLine(test.GetExample());
```

That way you hide away the fields but also enforce the constructor only accessiblity of read only fields.